# Body Background overflow

Tags: html, css

I did some UI practice and there is a problem with the background-image to body tag. The image is overflowing horizontally and I want to get rid of that. Plz help me.

Code how I tried to fixed it.

```
<style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: url("public/res/bg(WT).png") no-repeat fixed center center;
            background-size: cover;
        }
    </style>
```

The problem illustration : (red box)

[image]

My full code is like

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
body {
            background: url("public/res/bg(WT).png") no-repeat fixed center center;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
//contents are here
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you put this in plunkr? So we can debug. Because so far i see the problem with your image. The CSS looks ok.

Comment: At first sight, it looks like the problem does not come from the background image but from some margins

Comment: I did margin and padding for all tag 0. @Weedoze

Comment: The image resolution is 1920x1080px. I thought of that is problem too but I don't know what to do @Smit

Comment: You should share your code. Without seeing your code it is impossible to find the problem

Comment: @WaiLinAung the image resolution won't matter since you have already used `background-size: cover;`

Comment: You may want try this out, by adding the following code to your css. `-webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;` @Lucian that may work for some browsers only.

Comment: Please reproduce your problem inside a JSfiddle or plunkr

Comment: @Smit http://prntscr.com/edva1v it supports all modern browser. http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Comment: I did cross browser code too but not ok @Smit

Comment: @WaiLinAung can't you share your whole code in JSfiddle or the code snippet here? or if the site is live, could you give the link?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't share yet.

Comment: then it would be very difficult to help, sorry

Comment: I'll inform when I can share. I'm trying to share. Thanks sir. @Lucian

Comment: I've uploaded the site. Please go to mmlicence.web44.net @Lucian

Comment: i have posted the answer, please check @WaiLinAung

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap the entire content below `<body>` with a `div` and apply `overflow: hidden` for it.

```
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/872tR.png take this as a reference. i have wrapped everything except the script and the div as i think that was generated with JS. remove `overflow-x` from `<body>`

in any project, make it a rule to follow this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
body {
            background-image: url("http://unsplash.it/2500/1000");
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position:center;
            background-attachment: fixed;
           
        }
```

```html
<body>

</body>
```